# SGDClassifier with constraints

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to do logistic regression on a huge data set using scikit-learn `SGDClassifier` (I am using `partial_fit` to be precise). The coefficients I obtained are of different sign, whereas I would like to force the classifier to look only for positive values (I know it may not be the best approach in terms of methodology however it is what would be ok for now).

My question is:
Is there any way to impose constraints on coefficients using `SGDClassifier`?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with `SGDClassifier` in its current implementation.

If you wanted to implement this, you have to add a penalty, call it e.g. 'positivity', which makes sure this constraint is verified by placing infinite cost on negative values.

It may be possible to implement this using e.g. [this paper, Duchi 2009](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume10/duchi09a/duchi09a.pdf) (but I think there are follow-ups in newer literature that could be more up to the job). What you need to do at every mini-batch is to project onto the positive orthant. This is done by simply setting all negative values the occur after a gradient step in the logistic loss to 0.

Comment: I was afraid that I will get such answer...
Thank you.